# implement creative sdk on cordova (ionic)

Tags: android, cordova, aviary, adobecreativesdk

i would like to implement the creativesdk-image editor(old time aviary) in my cordova app.
the plugins i've found are 2 years old and won't run since the sdk that was used is not working anymore(there is a new sdk), the issue is that the new sdk which runs on android required gradle and in my cordova app i ca't use gradle, is there a way to create a plugin for cordova which takes all the compiled classes from a android studio compiled gradle sdk and use it on cordova plugin for android ? (i am new to cordova and android gradle)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Angular Aviary SDK](https://github.com/m00s/angular-aviary)? This project is 3 months old in github and provides AngularJS integration through an ngAviary directive, like so:

```
<a href="#"
  target='<selector>'
  on-save-button-clicked='onSaveButtonClicked(id)'
  on-save='onSave(id, newURL)'
  ng-aviary> Edit photo </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Quick answer

Try using the new [Image Editor UI PhoneGap plugin](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/phonegap-plugin-csdk-image-editor) (Cordova compatible).

There is also a [PhoneGap template for this plugin](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/phonegap-template-csdk-image-editor), provided as a reference sample.

## More info

The Creative SDK team recently collaborated with PhoneGap to release plugins that are compatible with PhoneGap, Cordova, and Ionic.

[There a details on the Creative SDK blog](https://blog.creativesdk.com/2016/09/phonegap-plugin-roundup/).

You can get a quick overview of everything on offer on [the Creative SDK GitHub page's Plugins section](https://creativesdk.github.io/#plugins).